# Unsatisfied dependencies for type [...] with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point (using @Stateful EJB with CDI)

Tags: java, ejb-3.0, java-ee-6, cdi, seam3

I have the following code to manage two kinds of repositories. Both repository classes inherit an interface to allow reinitialization of their resources.

```
public interface CachingRepository
{
    public void invalidateCache();
}
```

Global, application-scoped repo:

```
@Named("globalRepo")
@ApplicationScoped
public class GlobalRepository implements CachingRepository
{
    private List<Category> categories;

    ...

    @Override
    public void invalidateCache()
    {
        categories = null;
    }

    ...
}
```

Per user, session-scoped repo:

```
@Named("userRepo")
@SessionScoped
//@Stateful         // <- NOTE HERE
public class UserRepository implements CachingRepository, Serializable
{
    private List<MyFile> files;

    @Override
    public void invalidateCache()
    {
        files = null;
    }

    ...
}
```

When injecting this (without `@Stateful`) into the context

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class MyHandler implements Serializable
{
    @Inject
    private UserRepository userRepo;

    ...
}
```

it works. However, when adding `@Stateful` to the `UserRepository` class, deployment fails with an exception saying:

```
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type [UserRepository] with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point [[field] @Inject private de.company.project.pack.MyHandler.userRepo]
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:275)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:244)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBean(Validator.java:107)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateRIBean(Validator.java:127)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBeans(Validator.java:346)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateDeployment(Validator.java:331)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.validateBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:366)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.WeldContainer.start(WeldContainer.java:83)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.services.WeldService.start(WeldService.java:76)
    ... 5 more
```

Adding the name of the CDI bean like

```
@Inject @Named("userRepo")
private UserRepository userRepo;
```

results in the same exception. The only thing that works in conjunction with `@Stateful` is to use the interface in the var declaration:

```
@Inject @Named("userRepo")
private CachingRepository userRepo;
```

I might need sub class functionality here however, so using `CachingRepository` isn't really desired (at the moment).

**Q's**:

1. Why isn't this working as expected? The `UserRepository` var should already identify which class to instantiate, shouldn't it? What's the logic to this?
2. Why does the `@Stateful` EJB annotation have such severe effects here? Why does it essentially force me into using the `CachingRepository` interface in the var declaration?

---

**Note**, I' using Seam 3 Faces making the `@ViewScoped` become a CDI view-scoped bean, so the problem at hand is likely still **CDI-only**.

Comment: Oh, and BTW this seems to have been answered to some degree before here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9038815/weld-001408-unsatisfied-dependencies-when-injecting-ejbs-that-implement-interfac, but why "if you use an EJB you can't use the implementation anymore"? What's the logic behind this? Why isn't it possible anymore? This convention seems to exist, but why does it at all?

Comment: As I wrote, I don't see any sense it this and I am glad that it's not possible anymore so I can't help with that-)

Comment: Are you aware that you need `@Named` if and only if you need  JSF-access for a CDI managed bean? All it does is providing a qualified EL-name, it does **not** make a pojo to a CDI managed bean (that is 'done' by beans.xml) ...

Comment: Yes, I do. :-) The repos are displayed as dataTables to select files from and the view-scoped beans basically function as handlers for file uploads/removals (AJAX requests). As soon as one file gets added or removed, the list of respective repo files must be invalidated to be redisplayed. At least that's the current idea.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had the same problem with this misleading exception...

By adding `@Stateful` to `UserRepository` you expose EJB methods of the `CachingRepository` interface without having a no-interface view declared. Add `@LocalBean` to `UserRepository` to activate the no-interface view. See EJB 3.1 Specification, Section 4.9.8 "Session Bean's No-Interface View"

> The bean class must designate that it exposes a no-interface view via its bean class definition or in the deployment descriptor. The following rules apply:
>
> - ...
> - If the bean exposes at least one other client view, the bean
>     designates that it exposes a no-interface view by means of the
>     @LocalBean annotation on the bean class or in the deployment
>     descriptor.
> - ...

I also refer to [this stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7729905/what-is-local-remote-and-no-interface-view-in-ejb) answer for more information about no-interface views.

Comment: I don't have any EJB. I am not even using any @Default annotation anywhere in my code. But still at the time of Wildfly startup it's throwing this exception. I have searched a lot but everyone is talking about EJB.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error.

> Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408:
>   Unsatisfied dependencies for type UserTransaction with qualifiers
>   @Default at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject...

I solved this problem like this:
I used UserTransaction this way when I received an error.

```
@Inject
UserTransaction trans;
```

Instead of `@Inject`, I used `@Resource` annotation.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

And this is what I did to resolve it:

I had to produce the EJB I am trying to inject as below with a wildfly container:

```
@ApplicationScoped
    public class Resources {
     private static final String DISCOUNT_SERVICE_ENDPOINT_PROPERTY =
        "services.discount.endpoint";
     private MyServiceImpl myService;
    }

@Produces
 public MyServiceImpl produceMyServiceImpl() {
     if (myService == null) {
         String endpoint = System.getProperty(DISCOUNT_SERVICE_ENDPOINT_PROPERTY);
        JaxWsProxyFactoryBean factory = new JaxWsProxyFactoryBean();
        factory.setServiceClass(MyServiceImpl.class);
        factory.setServiceName(MyService.SERVICE);
        factory.setAddress(endpoint);
        myService = (MyServiceImpl) factory.create();
     }
     return myService;
```

}

The below is a config which goes under your standalone-full.xml file.

```
<property name="services.discount.endpoint" value="http://localhost:8080/my_service/MyService/MyServiceImpl"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should add non-parameterized Constructor on the bean class.
I read on Jboss Documentation that says: concrete  Java  class  that  has  a  constructor  with  no  parameters  (or  a constructor  designated  with  the  annotation  @Inject)  is  a  bean.

Comment: Welcome to community! Suggestions like this or partial solutions should be written as comments, not answers. Answers should only be written when they contain full solutions and answers every single OP's question.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. I hope this can help someone.

To solve the problem:

- Right click on projcet
- Click on `Properties`
- find `Project facets`
- On `Project facets`, active the option CDI
- Apply and save.

Now all is fine.

Comment: What's the IDE you're talking about? Please provide a context.